# Trying to make a AFK Change Nickname discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Where do i change to make a afk changeing name infront of nickname ?
example: [AFK]nickname
using code from https://github.com/Tomato6966/Multipurpose-discord-bot

here the afk code :

```
  MessageEmbed
} = require("discord.js");
const config = require(`${process.cwd()}/botconfig/config.json`);
const ee = require(`${process.cwd()}/botconfig/embed.json`);
const emoji = require(`${process.cwd()}/botconfig/emojis.json`);

module.exports = {
  name: "afk",
  category: "Settings",
  aliases: ["awayfromkeyboard",],
  cooldown: 10,
  usage: "afk [TEXT]",
  description: "Set yourself AFK",
  type: "user",
  run: async (client, message, args, user, text, prefix, player) => {
    let es = client.settings.get(message.guild.id, "embed");let ls = client.settings.get(message.guild.id, "language")
    try {
      if(args[0]) client.afkDB.set(message.guild.id+user.id, args.join(" "), "message");
      client.afkDB.set(message.guild.id+user.id, Date.now(), "stamp");
      message.reply(`You are now afk for: ${args.join(" ")}\n**Tip:** *Write \`[afk]\` infront of your Message to stay afk but still write*`);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(String(e.stack).grey.bgRed)
      return message.reply({embeds : [new MessageEmbed()
        .setFooter(client.getFooter(es)).setColor(es.wrongcolor)
        .setTitle(client.la[ls].common.erroroccur)
        .setDescription(eval(client.la[ls]["cmds"]["settings"]["afk"]["variable3"]))
      ]});
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With a user (here: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/User)
You can get the username. For example:

```
let afkUsername = `[AFK] ${user.username}`;
```

I think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: If you're using discord.js's **CommandInteraction/slash commands** you can modify the user's nickname with `await interaction.setNickname(afkUsername);`